# why doesnt a process resume from sleep() when new request received on a nonblocking server socket?

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, sleep

I am running linux 4.13.3, gcc 7.2.0.

the related code is sth. like that

```
while(1) {
    // let server be the nonblocking server socket
    int client = accept(server, &addr, &addrlen);
    if(client != -1) {
        foo(client);
    } else {
        sleep(someTime);
    }
}
```

I know I should use select/poll/epoll for that purpose,

but why doesnt the sleep() return when new data received on the socket ?

Comment: Because `sleep` does just put the process to sleep. There's no checking for events on file descriptors (unless it causes a signal). You probably want to use [`select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) or [`poll`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) instead.

Comment: So the real question should be, why there is no signal to the process when a related socket received data, right?

Comment: When I say "signal" I mean e.g. `SIGINT` or `SIGUSR1` or similar. Such signals are generally *not* generated by descriptors. If you want to receive notifications about sockets (or descriptors in general) start by learning about `select` or `poll` (as mentioned in my previous comment). Those are the common ways both to go to sleep *and* to poll for descriptor events. There are other ways to poll descriptors, but start with those two.

Comment: thanks. I find that a socket need to be configured for SIGIO, I thought it is a default option.

Comment: No it's not, and I highly advice you to learn about the simpler `select` and `poll` functions first. Then continue to more advanced topics like signals and `SIGIO`, and then continue to the Linux epoll system (which is harder to use but more powerful and flexible than the others).

Answer (score -1):

Do this before

```
void sig_handler(int sig){}
...
signal(SIGIO, sig_handler);
fcntl(server, SETOWN, getpid())
fcntl(server, SETFL, fcntl(server, GETFL) | O_NONBLOCKING | O_ASYNC);
...
```